# Convert string to camel case codewars

Tags: python

Прохожу задания в Codewars и появилась проблема в этом коде

```py
def to_camel_case(text):
    l = list(text)
    for i in l:
        if i == '_' or i == '-':
            l.remove(i)
            text = ''.join(l)
        elif len(text) == 0:
            return text
    return text
```

По условию задачи нужно убрать все знаки - и _, а после них буква должна быть заглавной. Основную задачу выполнил, но вот как сделать буквы заглавными не знаю как.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/

Comment: О командах этих я знаю, но не знаю как их правильно использовать для того, чтобы сделать определённые символы заглавными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. Мы смотрим на пару рядом стоящих символов. Если она соответствует _буква, то меняем на заглавную.

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    l = list(text)
    res=[]
    i=0
    while i< len(text)-1:
        if (l[i] in ['_','-']):
            if l[i+1] not in ['_','-']:
                res.append(l[i+1].upper())
                i=i+2
        else:
            res.append(l[i])
            i=i+1

    return ''.join(res)
```

Comment: Вместо `['_','-']` лучше использовать строку на два символа: `'_-'`, например: `if l[i] in '_-':`

Answer (score 5):

```
import  re
a = 'hjshf-df45_fsdf-fgbcn-puiouio'

print(''.join(map(str.capitalize, re.findall(r'[^-_]+', a))))
# HjshfDf45FsdfFgbcnPuiouio
```

Answer (score 3):

Регуляркой ищем пары из `-` / `_` с любым **символом** после них и заменяем их на **символ** в верхнем регистре:

- [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub) — это функция для замены строки на другую строку, аналог `str.replace`
- `[-_]` — ожидается один из символов: `-` или `_`
- `(.)` — точка `.` означает любой символ, а круглые скобки `()` нужны для захвата символа, чтобы получить его через `.group()`

Пример:

```
import  re

text = 'hjshf-df45_fsdf-fgbcn-puiouio'
print(text)

new_text = re.sub(r'[-_](.)', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), text)
print(new_text)
# hjshfDf45FsdfFgbcnPuiouio
```

Comment: Первая группа символов не подходит под шаблон регулярки в вашем варианте

Comment: @Wairua, по моему, ошибки нет. На мой взгляд результат соответствует ожидаемому, плюс с тем же наборов данных такой же результат как у вашего кода

Comment: На первую букву в выводе обратите внимание

Comment: Хотя Вы наверное правы, в задании речь идет о символах после знаков

Comment: Поэтому, либо задача не четко сформулирована, либо ваш вариант точнее

Comment: @Wairua, бывает, спасибо за код-ревью, хех :)

Answer (score 1):

Заменяем `-` и `_` на пробелы, капитализируем каждое слово, убираем пробелы.

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    return text.replace('-',' ').replace('_',' ').title().replace(' ','')
```

Comment: Странный будет результат для текста с пробелами :)

Comment: Можете привести пример? Например, `apple orange red` превратиться в `AppleOrangeRed`.

Comment: Угу, а по задаче нужно после `-` или `_` проводить удаление и приведение в верхний регистр, про пробелы этого не было сказано :) Возможно, на тестовых строках нет пробелов и тогда ваш код отработает без последствий :)

Comment: А, дошло, т. е. например `foo bar apple_orange` должно превратиться в `foo bar AppleOrange`, а не `FooBarAppleOrange`. Тогда Вы правы, что только в строках где нет пробелов код отработает верно.

Answer (score 0):

Проходим по всем символам, если нашли - или _ - удаляем его, и, если следующий за - или _ символ - буква, приводим к её верхнему регистру.

```
def to_camel_case(text):
  text_arr = list(text)
  i = 0
  while i < len(text_arr):
    if text_arr[i] == '-' or text_arr[i] == '_':
      del text_arr[i]
      if i != len(text_arr) - 1 and text_arr[i].isalpha():
        text_arr[i] = text_arr[i].upper()
        i += 1
    else:
      i += 1
  return ''.join(text_arr)
```

Comment: Конвертить строку в список нет смысла, т. к. строка итак является списком символов.

Comment: @Jazzis, имеет смысл если нужно удалять элементы и менять по индексам. Строка неизменяемый объект, поэтому такое в ней не сделать

Comment: Ваша правда, поторопился с комментарием :)